# Selenium+python Reporting

Tags: python, selenium

I am doing some R&D on selenium+python. I wrote some test cases in python using selenium webdriver and unittest module. I want to know how can I create report of the test cases. Is there inbuilt solution available in selenium or I need to code to generate file.

Or is there any other web testing framework with javascript support available in python which have reporting functionality.

I am basically new to python as well as selenium. Just trying to explore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To start building test reports on top of Selenium+Python, I would leverage the python unittest module. You will get a basic sample in Selenium documentation [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#using-selenium-to-write-tests).

Then [HTMLTestRunner](http://tungwaiyip.info/software/HTMLTestRunner.html) module combined with unittest provides basic but robust HTML reports.

Answer (score 4):

Use HTMLTestRunner

Go to below URL :

http://tungwaiyip.info/software/HTMLTestRunner.html

- Click on HTMLTestRunner.py
- Copy all code
- Create a file in your project with name HTMLTestRunner.py and dump the code
- Now import that file in your script using import keyword
- In main method call HTMLTestRunner

Example code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest
import HTMLTestRunner

class LoginTest(unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self):

    print driverpath
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(driverpath + "chromedriver.exe")
    self.driver.get("http://google.com/")

def testPythonScript(self):
    driver=self.driver
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.implicitly_wait(60)
    driver.get_screenshot_as_file(screenshotpath + "testPngFunction.png")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//a[contains(@href,'contact-us')])[1]").click()
    driver.find_element_by_name("name").send_keys("shubham")
    driver.find_element_by_id("contactemail").send_keys("shubham.xyz@abc.com")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#contact_form > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(3) > input").send_keys(
        "389198318312")
    driver.find_element_by_name("company").send_keys("myname")
    driver.get_screenshot_as_file(screenshotpath + "ConatctUs.png")
    print driver.title
    assert "Hello" in driver.title
    print "execution ends"

def testPythonFailScript(self):
    driver=self.driver
    driver.find_element_by_name("notExist").send_keys("done")

    def tearDown(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.quit();

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HTMLTestRunner.main()
```

Now open terminal and fire below command

```
python scriptFileName.py > TestReport.HTML
```

Note: scriptFileName is a python file name and TestReport is html report name. you can name it as you want

Answer (score 1):

My experience has been that any sufficiently useful test framework will end up needing a customized logging solution.  You are going to end up wanting domain specific and context relevant information, and the pre-baked solutions never really fit the bill by virtue of being specifically designed to be generic and broadly applicable.  If you are already using Python, I'd suggest looking in to the `logging` module and learning how to write Handlers and Formatters.  It's actually pretty straight forward, and you will end up getting better results than trying to shoehorn the logging you need in to some selenium-centric module.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [robot framework](http://www.robotframework.org). It has a plugin for selenium, and robot produces very nice logs and reports. With robot you don't directly write your tests in python (though, I suppose you can). Instead, robot is a keyword-based testing system built on top of python.

Answer (score 1):

[Robot Framework](http://robotframework.org/) is a functional test framework that makes it possible for its users to:

- Write tests in easily understood language
- Organize what tests are run for specific purposes
- Generate both high level and detailed test results

  - RF results file
  - RF log file
  - HTML page

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my specific application I use the [Nose](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose/) unittest extension for writing and running test suites.

On top of that I use an [html-reporting](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose-html-reporting) plugin that produces nice reports from my test cycles.

Comment: can you please share sample code and configuration steps which required

Comment: especially please provoide the steps to genrate reports